# In C# How do you read from DOS program you executed if the program is constantly outputting?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cmd

I have found many examples of coding on how to execute cmd.exe and execute a command, and execute even nslookup and interact, but the problem I am having is with a particular dos program that when it starts, it does not stop "outputting".  here is some code and I will put a comment and the errors I get from C#

Here is how I have it setup in a more advanced way so I can receive output from the program on events

```
public void StartApplication(string appNameAndPath)
{
        StreamReader outputStream;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = appNameAndPath;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;//for now just so I can see it
        p.Start();
//here is my advanced example
if(advanced == true)
{
        outputStream = p.StandardOutput;
        DoReadOutPut();
}
else
{//here is a simple example 
    while (p.StandardOutput.ReadLine() != null)  //this hangs here until the application exists
    {
        txt += (p.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
    }
}
}

 void DoReadOutput()
 {
        outputStream.BaseStream.BeginRead( readOutputBuffer, 0, readOutputBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback( OnReadOutputCompleted ), null );  
       //this does sometimes fire but only with 0 bytes, on other dos programs it would say Memory read not allowed
 }

 void OnReadOutputCompleted( IAsyncResult result )
 {
        int cbRead = outputStream.BaseStream.EndRead( result );
        ProcessOutput( readOutputBuffer, cbRead );
        DoReadOutput();
 }

 private void ProcessOutput(byte[] buffer, int cbRead)
 {
        string text = p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding.GetString(buffer, 0, 10000); //this is where it hangs until the program exits or is not writing anymore
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {

            SetTextBoxValue(text);//im doing this because im on another thread otherwise textBox1.Text - text"

        });
  }
```

I do not want to have to use API and `GetText` and create an engine to `ReadLastLine`, can anyone help me with this?  I suppose you would want an example exe, creating a C# application that `while(true){Console.WriteLine("bla");}` would suffice as the example exe but not the exe I am having trouble with.  The exe takes over the dos window and has an "old school interface"

Comment: Have you tried using `Process.OutputDataReceived` event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I will give it a quick try

Comment: Diamondo25 I tried that and the program kept running and when I hit pause on debug it went to the line after sortProcess.WaitForExit();
and never entered the SortOutputHandler event

Comment: Are you sure that the program is outputting to stdout, and not stderr?

Comment: don't know the source, but thankfully they had a parameter to allow the output

Comment: Is it really a DOS program? Or just a Windows console application?

Answer (score 3):

async/await can help here....

```
await Exec(yourExe,parameters);
```

---

```
Task Exec(string exe,string args)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = exe;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.Arguments = args;

    var proc = Process.Start(psi);

    proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        this.Invoke((Action) (()=>richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine)));
    };

    proc.Exited += (s, e) => tcs.SetResult(null);

    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: will try this one now sir

Comment: this works above, only when I chose to hit control z or C or cancel on the DOS application, does the output go to the text box.  thanks for the try though

Comment: See the code in `OutputDataReceived`. It writes to `richTextBox1`. You can change it with console.Write.

Comment: so are you saying I should create another project type that's not winforms and use console.write instead?

Comment: No just an option. Use whatvever you like. Try for example `await Exec("ping", "www.google.com");`

Comment: works great with ping -t www.google.com, but just not proprietary dos apps, very odd

Comment: I found out the app has a arg to allow output so it must be explicitly not outputting  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle callback events to read streams:

```
  startInfo.UseShellExecute        = false;
  startInfo.CreateNoWindow         = true;
  startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  startInfo.RedirectStandardError  = true;

  Process proc = new Process();
  proc.StartInfo           = startInfo;
  proc.ErrorDataReceived  += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceiveHandler);
  proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceiveHandler);
  proc.Start();
  proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
  proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
  proc.WaitForExit();
```

- Code borrowed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653836/psexec-hang-while-being-executed-from-a-very-simple-c-sharp-or-c-gui-program-c)

Comment: actually I think I have tried this one before, but will get it a ride

Comment: one question in the post above their is no stream, I will look at borrowed code

Comment: this doesn't work because my process never exits or stops for input.  its the main twist in this whole post compared to the usual how do I interact with a cmd or dos based program =///

Comment: If you process never exits (weird, b/c at some point system will be at least shut down, or service may be stopped by user), then simply remove `WaitForExit()` call and your program will continue running.