# Hanging when process WaitForExit in for loop

Tags: c#

I am creating a GUI application using Visual C# 2010 (.NET Framework 3.5). How to change this my code to the no stops responding?

```
for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    Process myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i \"" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "\" " + "-y ";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

The convert program some time use the converting. How to show new form or messengebox the running application? I want it to respond the window.
History for loop:
[How do I do I loop through items in a list box and then remove that item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380451/how-do-i-do-i-loop-through-items-in-a-list-box-and-then-remove-that-item)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C# How do you read from DOS program you executed if the program is constantly outputting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151235/in-c-sharp-how-do-you-read-from-dos-program-you-executed-if-the-program-is-const)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WaitForExit`, unsurprisingly, will block the thread until the process has exited.
Alternatively, you can use the [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to get notified when the process has exited.

You will also need to set the `EnableRaisingEvents` property to `true` in order for the `Exited` event to be fired.

```
myProcess.EnabledRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
myProcess.Start();

void myProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //process has exited, implement logic here
    listBox1.Items.Remove...
}
```

Comment: *WaitForExit, unsurprisingly, will block the thread until the process has exited* Mind = Blown

Comment: Start my process use selected listbox item and if exit process start new process and use next selection in listbox. while end listbox item(s).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks answer!
Done this code:

```
        void myProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {

            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                button1.PerformClick();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All Done!!");
            }
        });
    }
```